# Compass and straightedge constructions

Tags: field-theory

I'm studying field theory and I was given an exercise:

> Is $\sqrt[3]2\cos\frac{2\pi}{34}+\sqrt5\cos\frac{2\pi}{10}$ a constructible point ?

Any hints ?

Comment: btw: How can I do a third root notation in tex ?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{}$ is written as `\sqrt[3]` in TeX!

Comment: Or \root3\of{}.

Comment: A comprehensive book on ruler/compass and other geometric construction techniques and theory is available in the excellent book by George Martin: Geometric Constructions, Springer, 1998.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: If you're ready to solve this exercise, you should already know the answers to:

1. Is $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$ constructible?
2. Is $b=\cos\frac{2\pi}{34}$ constructible?
3. Is $c=\sqrt{5}$ constructible?
4. Is $d=\cos\frac{2\pi}{10}$ constructible?

What do the anwers to these four questions imply about the constructibility of $ab+cd$?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a 5-step proof:

1. Show that $\cos \frac{1}{5} \pi$ and $\cos \frac{1}{17} \pi$ are both constructible.
2. Show that $\sqrt{5}$ is constructible.
3. Show that the sum and product of two constructible numbers are constructible, and show that the additive and multiplicative inverses of a (non-zero) constructible number are constructible.
4. Show that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is *not* constructible.
5. Suppose $\sqrt[3]{2} \cos \frac{1}{17} \pi + \sqrt{5} \cos \frac{1}{5} \pi$ is constructible and deduce a contradiction.